# Solving system of 3 equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How do I solve the following system?

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
x_o = 4 - x_r \\ 
x_r = -2 - x_s \\ 
x_s = 2 - x_r
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

All the techniques i've found for solving 3-equation systems rely on all equations containing all the variables, whereas I don't see it in this case. When I try to isolate one of the factors and substitute it, it carries another factor with it:

$$
x_s = 2 - (-2 -x_s) \\
x_s = 2 + 2 + x_s \\
-2 = 2
$$

Comment: This does contain all the variables - write  $x_o=0*x_o + -1*x_r + 0*x_s + 4$, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your system does not have any solutions. The second equation says $x_s+x_r=-2$, whereas the last equation says $x_s+x_r=2$. This is not possible, hence inconsistent system.